# CallerMemberName not working in AzureFunctionsVersion v4

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function using `AzureFunctionsVersion v3` and `CallerMemberName` is working. Another function is `AzureFunctionsVersion v4` and using the same code, `CallerMemberName` is empty:

```
public async Task TheMethod(dynamic messageJSON, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "")
```

The method is two deep in a call:

```
ProcessMessage(string messageText, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "")
{
  // callerMemberName in ProcessMessage works
  // callerMemberName in TheMethod is ""
  TheMethod(messageText);
}
```

Is there something different about `AzureFunctionsVersion v4` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?msclkid=69683050b9e511ecaf334384562005dd&tabs=in-process,v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp) shows difference between v3 and v4.

The main difference would be that v3 use **.NET core3.1** and v4 use **.NET6** .

But according the following documentation of [.netcore3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?msclkid=ae403e58b9e211ec96036aa8a96cb3a7&view=netcore-3.1) and  [.net6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0) the implementation of using `CallerMemberName` to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method remains the same .